# Carabiner including relative background-image in CSS

Tags: php, codeigniter

While including the background image in CSS

```
div{
  background-image:url("../css/images/photostack/prev.png");
}
```

Carbiner minifies it which is displayed as

```
div{
    background-image: url("http://localhost/my_proj/public/css/slider.css../css/images/photostack/prev.png");
}
```

hence not being able to access the required png file.

How should I correct it ?

I have my project as

```
my_proj
|
|- application
|  |- .........
|  ..........
|
|- public
   |- js
   |
   |- css
      |
      |- slider.css
      |
      |- images
         |
         |- photostack
            |
            |- prev.png
```

I have configured the carbiner's config as :

```
    //carabiner minifier
    $this->load->library('carabiner');
    $carabiner_config = array(
        'script_dir' => base_url().'public/js', 
        'style_dir'  => base_url().'public/css',
        'cache_dir'  => 'cache',
        'base_uri'   => base_url(),
        'combine'    => TRUE,
        'dev'        => FALSE
    );
    $this->carabiner->config($carabiner_config);
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used this, but after a quick reading of the carabiner documentation I found out the error :

> script_dir
>
> STRING Path to the script directory.  Relative to the CI front controller (index.php)
>
> style_dir
>
> STRING Path to the style directory.  Relative to the CI front controller (index.php)

Yes, as you may have already guessed, it's the base_url() helper that you are adding to the config array. the paths should be relative to index.php, so basically you just need to do this :

```
'script_dir' => 'public/js', 
'style_dir'  => 'public/css',
```

Comment: Changing it as `'script_dir' => 'public/js',` and `'style_dir' => 'public/css',` made no difference.

Comment: simply because you are setting dev to false, which means that cashing is activated :) maybe you should read the docs thoroughly
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/103890/